# How can I convert my gene data into a sparse matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, correlation

I have a csv file that has data arranged in the following format:

```
  Species     Transcripts per million        ARG             subtype
  Ktedonobacter racemifer   40.1956726 macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin  macB
  Ktedonobacter racemifer   16.1032353 macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin  macB
  Ktedonobacter racemifer   11.94756169 macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin macB
  Ktedonobacter racemifer   4.827971857 macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin macB
  Ktedonobacter racemifer   0   beta-lactam penA
  Kutzneria albida  31.74637821 beta-lactam penA
  Kutzneria albida  30.05937261 beta-lactam penA
  Kutzneria albida  18.00431172 beta-lactam penA
  Kutzneria sp. 744 16.78071772 beta-lactam penA
```

I would like to convert the data that appears in the top so that it sums up the Transcripts per million (these are the numbers) if it appears in the same species and gene (In the example data I added the TPMs for macB gene since it appears in Ktedonobacter racemifer). Then I would like to arrange it in sparse format like the table below. Are there any R gurus that could help me with this? Thanks!

```
                        macB    penA
Ktedonobacter racemifer 73.07       0
Kutzneria albida            0   79.81
Kutzneria sp. 744           0    16.7
```

I've tried to read it in as a .csv, create a matrix and convert it to a sparse matrix but I get an error code...likely because I am not familiar with the Matrix module

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that...do you have a command?

Comment: once you read the data in R, you could `dput(df)` where `df` is the dataframe name.

Comment: structure(list(Species = c("[Polyangium] brachysporum", "Abditibacterium utsteinense", 
"Abditibacterium utsteinense", "Acaryochloris sp. RCC1774", "Acetobacteraceae bacterium AT-5844", 
"Achromobacter sp. DH1f"), TPM = c(12.68819358, 43.64681628, 
11.63915101, 31.8951603, 14.33518658, 12.04469634), ARG.like.ORF = c("vancomycin", 
"multidrug", "multidrug", "vancomycin", "multidrug", "macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin"
), subtype = c("vanS", "mexT", "mexT", "vanS", "bicyclomycinmultidrugeffluxproteinbcr", 
"macB")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you will use `aggregate` then `xtabs` with the same formula:

```
xtabs(Transcripts.per.million~Species+subtype,aggregate(.~Species+subtype,df,sum))
                         subtype
Species                       macB     penA
  Ktedonobacter racemifer 73.07444  0.00000
  Kutzneria albida         0.00000 79.81006
  Kutzneria sp.744         0.00000 16.78072
```

Comment: Hi Onyambu thanks for your help...looks like this could be a simple solution but I am getting an error.   >xtabs(TPM~Species+subtype,aggregate(.~Species+subtype,ARG,sum))
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: @user3105519 can you do `aggregate(TPM~Species+subtype,ARG,sum)` and check whether that works

Comment: You are a life saver....simply shocked that was so easy! Now if I did not want to sum any could I just leave that out?

Comment: @user3105519 am sorry I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry I meant if I do not want to sum the values....can I leave "sum" out of the script?

Comment: @user3105519 no need of the `aggregate` part at all.